Color highlighting of polygon in WMS
I'm pretty new to WMS Services.
I do a "GetFeatureInfo" request on a WMS service. The metadata also contains a polygon geometry of a place that I am interested in, and that I want to highlight in the final image.
When doing the "GetMap" request, I provide a BBOX with the desired area.
But is there a way to pass the polygon to highlight it ?
I read something about "HIGHLIGHT_GEOM" query parameter, but this seems to be ignored by the WMS server.
Doing a postprocessing of the image sounds terrifying to me.

Hightlight is something that is not directly supported by the WMS standard but there are some workarounds. See for example https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173867/highlight-a-feature-in-a-wms-map-image. In a browser application it might be easiest to capture the feature geometry and render that on top of the WMS map as a separate layer. See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139832/highlight-a-feature-on-wms-layer-using-ol3-mapserver

You can send a custom SLD as part of a GetMap request if you know the id of the underlying feature, and the WMS will return an image with the polygon coloured up according to your sent style
