# Adding WMS layer with CQL filter

Tags: geoserver, javascript, leaflet, wms, cql-filter

I would like to add to my leaflet's web map layer from my WMS service (Geoserver), but I need to use CQL filter in GetMap link:

> `localhost/geoserver/my_location/wms?(...)&CQL_FILTER=[...]`

Is it possible? Please, help ;)

edit:

```
var heatmap = L.tileLayer.wms('http://my_wms_adress:8080/geoserver/my_location/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=my_location:my_location_history&styles=&bbox=54.406021,18.531216,54.497708,18.577851&width=768&height=390&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers&CQL_FILTER=user_id=1', {layers: 'my_location_history', format: 'image/png',transparent: true})
```

As you can see I added all parameters, but IMHO it's wrong, but I am not sure how to do it. Can I skip parameters like bbox, width, height and add only CQL_FILTER?

Comment: please add in some of the code you have already tried along with a note of what is not working

Comment: I've added code above in my post.

Comment: Have you tried to add %27 (single quote) on both sides of your id?  i.e. CQL_FILTER=user_id=%271%27

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code contains:

> `&CQL_FILTER=user_id=1`

And I will guess that the two `=`s are messing up the URL.

---

In Leaflet WMS tilelayers, any extra options which are not defined will be passed to the WMS server as parameters in each request URL, so:

```
var layer = L.tileLayer.wms(
    'http://my_wms_adress:8080/geoserver/my_location/wms', 
    {
        layers: 'my_location_history',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
        CQL_FILTER: 'user_id=1'
    }
)
```

Note that you do **not** need to specify the WMS version, `request=GetMap` or any other standard WMS parameters in the URL template.

Also, do check the [Leaflet WMS tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html).

Comment: I usually use `encodeuricomponent()` while passing more complicated CQL filters

Answer (score 0):

var layer = L.tileLayer.wms(
    'http://my_wms_adress:8080/geoserver/my_location/wms', 
    {
        layers: 'my_location_history',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
        CQL_FILTER: 'user_id=\'1\'
    }
)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please, add more details in your answer to help the author and others.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, in ArcMap (10.1), you can add a WMS then go to the params and add the same CQL_FILTER in the properties of the WMS.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110399/passing-filter-parameters-to-geoserver-wfs-via-url)

adding `&CQL_FILTER=YOUR_FIELD='YourValue'` would just make it