# Downloading shapefile from geoserver after applying CQL filter?

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, cql

I have managed to download a zipped shapefile from geoserver but now I want to be able to download part of the layer in a shapefile. This is what I did in order to download the whole layer as shapefile:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?format_options=charset%3AUTF-8&typename=something%3layer_1&outputFormat=SHAPE-ZIP&version=1.0.0&service=WFS&request=GetFeature
```

I have also managed to apply a single CQL filter based on the answer of [Passing Filter Parameters to GeoServer WFS via URL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110399/passing-filter-parameters-to-geoserver-wfs-via-url)

How can I apply multiple CQL filters in the same URL? I read [Passing Filter Parameters to GeoServer WFS via URL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110399/passing-filter-parameters-to-geoserver-wfs-via-url) that I need to encode the 'and' string in the CQL part of the URL. Is there an example illustrating this?

Comment: Read the comment more carefully. What needs to be encoded is not "AND" but the spaces around it. The result after encoding is `%20AND%20`.

Comment: Its not necessary to encode the spaces. The browser takes care of it automatically.

Comment: It is necessary to encode the spaces somewhere and while browsers may do it it automatically the referenced question was dealing with PHP's CURL. It seems that it required explicit url-encoding.