# How to return a value from the database just by using Geoserver?

Tags: postgis, geoserver

There's a spatial table in Postgis with polygon geometry, a column with id and a column with the needed value. There are several users who input points in a website

The coordinates of these points fall within a certain polygon in this table, the website needs the values from the polygon table.

In other words, the input would be lat, lon. And the output would be a 5 letter value reference.

Is it possible for Geoserver to return this value reference? and if so how to do it? Or is it better to build a function on the database?

Comment: A simple WFS query would do this, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @iant select value into ref
  from schema.table
  where ST_Contains(schema.table.geom, ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(p_lon, p_lat),4326),27700)); 
  return ref

but doesnt work in geoserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WFS reference](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html) should provide what you need. You can run a WFS request on a layer and GeoServer will reply all data that fulfills the query, including the columns that you have exposed in your database (unless you have chosen to hide them when you created the GeoServer layer).

For the coordinates you may use the BBOX parameter, i.e.:

```
http://example.com/geoserver/wfs?
  service=wfs&
  version=2.0.0&
  request=GetFeature&
  typeNames=namespace:featuretype&
  srsName=CRS&
  bbox=a1,b1,a2,b2
```

You can not define a null-sized filter, however. That means you can not ask a feature at an exact (*lat*,*lon*) coordinate. But you can query a small box around it, e.g. from (*lat*-0.01,*lon*-0.01) to (*lat*+0.01,*lon*+0.01).

The result will be in GML by default. If you are not familiar with it, I suggest you use another outputformat such as csv by adding `&outputFormat=csv` at the end of the request.

As a last note, be careful about the WFS version. For WFS 1.0.0 the BBOX parameter uses *lon1*,*lat1*,*lon2*,*lat2* but in WFS 2.0.0 this is *lat1*,*lon1*,*lat2*,*lon2*.

Comment: you could also use a contains filter - see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110399/passing-filter-parameters-to-geoserver-wfs-via-url for more details